# Select display profiles in iTerm for OS X

Tags: macos, iterm

I've recently started using iTerm for OS X, and I can see how to edit and create display profiles, but not how to choose one for the current session or to be the new default (and I can't imagine why that's so obscure).  As a result, for now, I've customized my Light Background profile to be a dark-background profile, but I'd like to know how to handle this properly.

On a side note, how would I reset a profile to its originally-installed configuration?

Comment: Try iTerm2 <http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/> which is based on iTerm and has changed profiles etc

Answer (score 1):

This is done in the bookmarks manager.

- Go to "Bookmarks -> Manage Bookmarks..."
- Choose the "Default" entry, then click the edit icon. This is the little pencil at the bottom of the Bookmarks manager window.
- Choose your new default display profile and click "OK" to save your settings.

New iTerm windows will now use your new default display profile.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little surprised there isn't a context menu for it, but you should be able to select a profile via the Profiles menu in the menubar.

I don't see a way to reset a profile; I expect you're supposed to clone the profile (Preferences > Profiles, select Duplicate Profile from the gear / Other Actions menu), edit the new profile, then set it as default if you expect to want the original settings later.

Comment: I don't see a Profiles menu.  I see Bookmarks -> Manage Profiles, but I can't pick one from there -- only configure them.

Comment: Oh, is this 0.95?  Ditch it; it's dead (no longer being maintained).  http://sites.google.com/site/iterm2home/ is the current version.

Comment: Wow -- it's worse than that.  I have somehow managed to install version 0.10.  Thanks for the heads-up.